# AWS Lambda (NodeJS) does not log to cloudwatch

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to log my lambda app after following [serverless-next.js](https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js/issues/522) because of the issue where I can't go to the root of my file. So basically I'm deploying [nextJS](https://nextjs.org/) app in AWS through lambda@edge, s3, and cloudfront.

I'm new to AWS so I'm not really sure how to debug this thing at all. I assume traditional `console.log` in my lambda where every request comes in would log it in the cloudwatch. I also made sure that I deployed my lambda to my cloud front

Here's the code:

```
"use strict";
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.handler = void 0;
const prerender_manifest_json_1 = __importDefault(require("./prerender-manifest.json"));
const manifest_json_1 = __importDefault(require("./manifest.json"));
const next_aws_cloudfront_1 = __importDefault(require("@sls-next/next-aws-cloudfront"));
const addS3HostHeader = (req, s3DomainName) => {
    req.headers["host"] = [{ key: "host", value: s3DomainName }];
};
const isDataRequest = (uri) => uri.startsWith("/_next/data");
const normaliseUri = (uri) => (uri === "/" ? "/index" : uri);
const normaliseS3OriginDomain = (s3Origin) => {
    if (s3Origin.region === "us-east-1") {
        return s3Origin.domainName;
    }
    if (!s3Origin.domainName.includes(s3Origin.region)) {
        const regionalEndpoint = s3Origin.domainName.replace("s3.amazonaws.com", `s3.${s3Origin.region}.amazonaws.com`);
        return regionalEndpoint;
    }
    return s3Origin.domainName;
};
const router = (manifest) => {
    const { pages: { ssr, html } } = manifest;
    const allDynamicRoutes = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, ssr.dynamic), html.dynamic);
    return (uri) => {
        let normalisedUri = uri;
        if (isDataRequest(uri)) {
            normalisedUri = uri
                .replace(`/_next/data/${manifest.buildId}`, "")
                .replace(".json", "");
        }
        if (ssr.nonDynamic[normalisedUri]) {
            return ssr.nonDynamic[normalisedUri];
        }
        console.log(uri);
        for (const route in allDynamicRoutes) {
            const { file, regex } = allDynamicRoutes[route];
            const re = new RegExp(regex, "i");
            const pathMatchesRoute = re.test(normalisedUri);
            if (pathMatchesRoute) {
                return file;
            }
        }
        if (html.nonDynamic["/404"] !== undefined) {
            return "pages/404.html";
        }
        return "pages/_error.js";
    };
};
exports.handler = (event) => __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const uri = normaliseUri(request.uri);
    const manifest = manifest_json_1.default;
    const prerenderManifest = prerender_manifest_json_1.default;
    const { pages, publicFiles } = manifest;
    const isStaticPage = pages.html.nonDynamic[uri];
    const isPublicFile = publicFiles[uri];
    const isPrerenderedPage = prerenderManifest.routes[request.uri];
    const origin = request.origin;
    const s3Origin = origin.s3;
    const isHTMLPage = isStaticPage || isPrerenderedPage;
    const normalisedS3DomainName = normaliseS3OriginDomain(s3Origin);
    s3Origin.domainName = normalisedS3DomainName;
    if (isHTMLPage || isPublicFile) {
        s3Origin.path = isHTMLPage ? "/static-pages" : "/public";
        addS3HostHeader(request, normalisedS3DomainName);
        if (isHTMLPage) {
            request.uri = `${uri}.html`;
        }
        return request;
    }
    const pagePath = router(manifest)(uri);
    if (pagePath.endsWith(".html")) {
        s3Origin.path = "/static-pages";
        request.uri = pagePath.replace("pages", "");
        addS3HostHeader(request, normalisedS3DomainName);
        return request;
    }
    const page = require(`./${pagePath}`);
    const { req, res, responsePromise } = next_aws_cloudfront_1.default(event.Records[0].cf);
    if (isDataRequest(uri)) {
        const { renderOpts } = yield page.renderReqToHTML(req, res, "passthrough");
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.end(JSON.stringify(renderOpts.pageData));
    }
    else {
        page.render(req, res);
    }
    return responsePromise;
});
```

Permission:

```
    Allow: logs:CreateLogGroup
    Allow: logs:CreateLogStream
    Allow: logs:PutLogEvents
```

What else should I do? Should I create a new stream or is it automatically created? I can see a log group in my cloudwatch named `aws/lambda` but i'm not sure how to connect them

Really appreciate any help

Cheers

Comment: Could you log in the handler to see if it's the logic or your logic? What if it's not even going to that function where you've put the log

Comment: A log group will be created by AWS based on your lambda function name. You need not create one.

Comment: It always return 404.html page and that's the only entry to it.. so it should be going to that function.. Is there any other way to debug lambda? I'm getting super confused